# footer and header will not width 100%

Tags: html, css, width, dreamweaver

Hey guys I have a problem here.

My header background & footer will not fill the site ;/
width is at 100% and should fill the area from the left to the right but there is a minimal space between the edges... I´m trying to fix that soo hard but nothing worked for me.

Have you guys some ideas ?

[Here is the link](http://michael-kalinski.de/de/home.html)

greets

Comment: I can see margin: 8px for BODY element style ! Set your BODY margin to 0px !important , See if this helps :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's due to body margins.

Try to apply this style to `body` tag:

`margin: 0;`

Comment: Crazy... I´ve set the body into my .wrap style... now it worked ?!?

Comment: Dreamweaver is such a serious thing ;( or i´m just dumb ... but finaly it worked! to work on body tag was the key. Thank you ;)

Answer (score 0):

You would want to do this with some .css code

```
    #footer {
        background: #000000;
        position: absolute;
        bottom: 0;
        width: 100%;
    }
```

Also check your meta-tags and make sure they are correct for the layout you are developing for. Hope this helps

Comment: Check your viewport tag and change static width to 100%

Answer (score 0):

Css resets are very handy for getting rid of these kind of issues. Try adding

- {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  }

For some reason the * renders as a dot, apply it to an *

Comment: I´ve solved the problem by putting the body into the wrapper. Now I want to bring up some content in my footer. Are there some Text Generators or layouts to create a stylish text ?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by a stylish text?

Answer (score 0):

On style.css file, on 8 line just add:

```
margin: 0 auto;
```

Here is a final code:

```
body {
font: 80% Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
margin: 0 auto;
}
```